# In R, when I store a variable in an index instead of using it directly, filter doesn't work

Tags: r, dplyr

For example :

```
filter(data, var=="A") #works

i <- "A"
filter(data, var==i) #empty table
```

Why ? Thank you.

Comment: Both should work. Please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it might be possible for others to identify the problem.

Comment: Do you have a column named `i` in your `data`? Something import is missing because this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = LETTERS[1:3])

i <- "B"

df %>% 
  filter(b == !!i)
#>   a b
#> 1 2 B
```

Comment: Sure but this should work without the `!!`.

Comment: Yes, @SamR, but maybe in the context the OP is doing that, this way may work.

Comment: Maybe - another possible thought is that `dplyr` is not loaded they are using `stats::filter()` instead - easy to do accidentally but I don't see why it would cause this behaviour. Hard to know without a reproducible example.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @SamR! That is why I have upvoted your comment where you ask for a reproducible example,

Comment: Thanks ! Idk why, but now everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `i` would be a column in the dataset.  In that case, it is easier to replicate the behavior

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = LETTERS[1:3], i = 5)
i <- "B"
df %>%
   filter(b == i)
[1] a b i
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If that is the case, use `.env` to extract the object from the global env

```
df %>% 
  filter(b == .env$i)
  a b i
1 2 B 5
```